# Unable to connect to MongoDB with Angular/Nestjs

Tags: angular, mongodb, nestjs

I try very hard to connect to mongoDB previously I was getting schema error that's has been remove one I downgraded version 5.9.2. Now it keeps giving me an error :

```
[Nest] 15624   - 12/03/2020, 10:29:35   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying 
(5)... +3002ms
```

I've checked everything from my side & found no problem is code. Also in research on stack many programmers have got this error due to using special char in password but in my case I don't use.

I copy my scripts hereunder. let me know pls if you could get anything.

config.ts

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

const result = dotenv.config();

if (result?.error) {
  throw new Error('Add .env file');
}

  export const config = {
  env: process.env.SZ_ENV,
  appName: process.env.SZ_APP,
  port: process.env.SZ_PORT,
  mongoUri:`mongodb+srv://${process.env.SZ_MONGO_USER}:${process.env.SZ_MONGO_PASS}
  @${process.env.SZ_MONGO_HOST}/${process.env.SZ_MONGO_DB}? 
  authSource=admin&replicaSet=${process.env.SZ_MONGO_REPLICA}&readPreference=primary&ssl=true`,
  };
```

.env

```
 SZ_APP=Schoolzone
 SZ_ENV=local
 SZ_PORT=3000
 SZ_MONGO_USER=service
 SZ_MONGO_PASS=school123
 SZ_MONGO_DB=localhost
 SZ_MONGO_HOST=schoolzone
 SZ_MONGO_REPLICA=vyian.mongodb.net
```

.env.example

```
SZ_APP=Schoolzone
SZ_ENV=local
SZ_PORT=3000
SZ_MONGO_USER=service
SZ_MONGO_PASS=school123
SZ_MONGO_DB=localhost
SZ_MONGO_HOST=schoolzone
SZ_MONGO_REPLICA=vyian.mongodb.net
```

package.json (dependencies)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.1.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "mongoose": "5.9.29",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { config } from './config';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) {}
  appStatus(): string {
    return `${config.appName} is running in port ${config.port}. Connected to 
   ${this.connection.name}`;
  }
 }
```

Please advise if anything further need to be copied here:

Comment: .. so where do you actually connect?

Comment: Good question, well I apparently need to connect MongoDB compass. Be informed that compass has successfully connected with Atlas